How can I simplify onPressed logic in my Python GUI framework to be more like Flutter?
I'm developing a GUI framework in Python that is inspired by Flutter. Currently, I handle onPressed events by passing the function name as a string and then registering the callbacks in my main.py file. Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing:
# ExampleWidget.py
button = Button(onPressed="handleClick")

# main.py
def handleClick():
    print("Button clicked!")

register_callback("handleClick", handleClick)

While this works, it feels cumbersome and error-prone. I would prefer a method that's as simple and precise as Flutter's approach, where you can directly pass the function as a callback without dealing with strings or separate registrations.
My goal: Simplify the onPressed logic so that it's more intuitive and closely resembles Flutter's design.
Questions:
How would you refactor this to avoid passing function names as strings?
What design patterns or techniques could I use to streamline this process?
Are there any best practices in Python that could help make this more elegant?
Additional Context:
The framework uses HTML and CSS for rendering the GUI in a PyWebView window.
I'm targeting desktop platforms like Ubuntu and Windows.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The Problem:
I wanted to avoid passing function names as strings and manually registering them. I aimed for a more intuitive API where function references are used directly, similar to Flutter.
Solution:
Singleton Api Class:
To manage callbacks efficiently, I used a singleton pattern for the Api class, ensuring there's only one instance managing callbacks.
# framework/api.py

class Api:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = {}

    _instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super(Api, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instance

    def register_callback(self, name, callback):
        self.callbacks[name] = callback

    def on_pressed(self, callback_name, index=None):
        if callback_name in self.callbacks:
            if index is not None:
                self.callbacks[callback_name](index)
            else:
                self.callbacks[callback_name]()
            return f"Callback '{callback_name}' executed successfully."
        else:
            return f"Callback '{callback_name}' not found."

Refactored IconButton Widget:
The IconButton class now directly uses function references for onPressed. The function name is extracted using name and used to register the callback.
# framework/widget.py

class IconButton(Widget):
    def __init__(self, child, onPressed=None, style=None):
        self.child = child
        self.onPressed = onPressed
        self.style = style or ButtonStyle()
        self.api = Api()

        self.onPressedName = self.onPressed.__name__ if self.onPressed else ''

    def to_html(self):
        button_id = f"icon_button_{id(self)}"
        style = self.style.to_css()
        child_html = self.child.to_html() if isinstance(self.child, Widget) else self.child

        # Register the callback with the API
        self.api.register_callback(self.onPressedName, self.onPressed)

        return f"""
        <button id='{button_id}' style='{style}' onclick='handleClick("{self.onPressedName}")'>
            {child_html}
        </button>
        """

How It Works:
Callback Registration: The Api class registers callbacks using the function name.
Button HTML: The IconButton class generates HTML with the function name included in the onclick attribute.
JavaScript Handling: A JavaScript function (not shown here) uses the function name to call the correct Python callback.
Request for Feedback:
I’ve implemented this approach to make the API more intuitive and avoid manual callback registration. I’d appreciate any insights or suggestions on:
Potential Improvements: Are there more efficient or cleaner ways to handle this?
Edge Cases: Are there edge cases I might have missed?
Design Patterns: Are there design patterns that could improve this approach?
Looking forward to your feedback!

In Python you can simply pass functions as arguments.
Also you can create a special type for your ButtonPress Function, so that the skeleton of your function is type-safe. Here f.e.
from type import Callable
ButtonFunction = Callable[[str, str], str]

